# PHP - product counter (odd and even numbers)

Tags: php, count

I need to be able to determine how many envelopes are required in my online store based on how many cards are in the customers basket. So:

```
1 card = 1 Single Envelope
2 cards = 1 Double Envelope
```

I have the following check:

```
$cards = 2
if ($number % 2 == 0) {
  // double envelope
}
else {
  // single envelope
}
```

Which works fine if they order 1 or 2 cards but if they order more I need to have the same logic but add up the envelopes. So if they had:

```
3 cards = 1 x Single & 1 x Double
4 cards = 2 x Double
15 cards = 1 x Single & 7 x Double
20 cards = 10 x Double
and so on...
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$cards = 4;
$doubles = floor($cards / 2);
$singles = $cards % 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$numDoubles = round($cards / 2, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
if($cards % 2 == 1) {
    $numSingles = 1;
} else {
    $numSingles = 0;
}
```

Edited to include round based on comment.

Comment: There is no integer division operator in PHP. 1/2 yields the float 0.5. The value can be casted to an integer to round it downwards, or the round() function provides finer control over rounding. Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php